Compute the flow of the vector field $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ on the manifold $M=S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$
Consider the manifold $M = S^1 \times \mathbb{R},$ with coordinates $(\theta,z) \in (0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R},$ and the vector field defined by $$X = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$ I would like to compute the flow. Where I am struggling is how to interpret plugging this into the differential equation $$\dot{c}_p(t) = X(c_p(t)).$$

$X$ is the pushforward of the vector field
$$\tilde X := \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^2),$$
where $\mathbb{R}^2$ has coordinates $(\theta,z)$, by the covering map
$$\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to S^1\times \mathbb{R}, \ (\theta, z) \mapsto (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta), z).$$
The flow of $\tilde X$ is given by
$$\Phi: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \ (t,\theta, z) \mapsto (t+\theta, t+z).$$
Therefore the flow of $X$ is given by
$$\Psi: \mathbb{R} \times (S^1 \times \mathbb{R}) \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$$ with
$$\Psi(t,\varphi(\theta,z)) = \varphi\circ\Phi(t,\theta,z),$$
i.e. $\Psi(t, \cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),z) = (\cos(t+\theta),\sin(t+\theta),t+z)$ for $\theta,z \in \mathbb{R}$.
